# Complexity: Formal syntax or notation misunderstanding

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am reading a complexity tutorial and I can't understand part of the notation:

> A function f(n) can be represented is the order of g(n) that is
>   O(g(n)), if there exists a value of positive integer n as n0 and a
>   positive constant c such that − f(n)⩽c.g(n) for n > n0 in all case

1. What is the meaning of the **dot** inside **c.g(n)** ?
2. Is the following a typo mistake? If not - what does it mean? What does the g(n) represent?

> A function f(n) can be represented **is** the order of g(n)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot `.` means multiplication so it is `c.g(n) == c x (g(n))`. And the second means `f(n)` can be write as `O(g(n))` if the mentioned condition is staisfied.